# How do I convert an object of objects to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am fetching an API endpoint which returns data in the format

```
    {
      "0": {
      "name": "Rohan"
       },
      "1": {
      "name": "Meghan"
      },
      "2": {
      "name": "Rita"
      }
   }
```

But since it is not array my map function throws an error

```
Home.jsx:39 Uncaught TypeError: users.map is not a function
```

Hence I want to convert this object of objects into a `const arrOfarr`. The array should look like:

```
    [
      {
      "name": "Rohan"
      },
      {
      "name": "Meghan"
      },
      {
      "name": "Rita"
      }
   ]
```

Comment: Assuming this is JavaScript: `Object.values()`

Comment: Either it is JSON, and there is no `map` method, or it is a JavaScript array. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can get key and value pairs with this line.

> Object.entries(yourObj)